# jQuery - scroll down every x seconds, then scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable div that I want to scroll down 50 pixels every X seconds.  That's fine and working.

I also have a seperate function that scrolls the div back to the top when it reaches the bottom.  Also fine; working.

Now, I need to combine the two so the scrolldown is ignored until we have scrolled to the top again.

I have a 'working' example here, as you'll see it has some pretty nutty behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/JVftf/

```
window.setInterval(scrollit, 3000);

function scrollit() {
    $('#scroller').delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: $("#scroller").scrollTop() + 50 }, 'slow');
}

$('#scroller').bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        $('#scroller').delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version:

```
var scrollingUp = 0;

window.setInterval(scrollit, 3000);

function scrollit() {
    if(scrollingUp == 0) {
        $('#scroller').delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: $("#scroller").scrollTop() + 50 }, 'slow');
    }
}

$('#scroller').bind('scroll', function () {
    $('#status').html(scrollingUp);

    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        scrollingUp = 1;      
        $('#scroller').delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000, function() {
            scrollingUp = 0;    
        });
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EFmeK/

Btw, in your jsfiddle, it scrolls 60px instead of 50px, which I "fixed" in my example.

Comment: Perfect.  Extra kudos for fixing my typo too.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/JVftf/3/

```
window.setInterval(scrollit, 1000);

function scrollit() {
    console.log(($("#scroller").scrollTop() + $("#scroller").innerHeight()))
    console.log($("#scroller")[0].scrollHeight)

    if(($("#scroller").scrollTop() + $("#scroller").innerHeight()) >= $("#scroller")[0].scrollHeight)   
        $('#scroller').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100).delay(900);  
    else   
        $('#scroller').animate({ scrollTop: $("#scroller").scrollTop() + 60 }, 'slow',function(){

    });
}
```

Comment: Looks good in chrome, but doesn't appear to work at all in IE9.