# How to automatically go to top after x seconds if user scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new. New to JS/CSS and Stack Overflow.

I have a `div` box with the CSS property `overflow: auto`.
If a user scrolls down in the DIV box, it should automatically scroll to the top again after x seconds.

Is this possible? And how is this possible?

I think it should detect if the scrollbar is not in the start position to let the countdown count.
After x seconds it should go back to top. Right?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - scroll down every x seconds, then scroll to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067190/jquery-scroll-down-every-x-seconds-then-scroll-to-the-top)

Comment: @UdhayTitus Hey thanks for your answer. No Im sorry - I just want that it scoll back if someone scrolled the div. The countdown should start when the scrollbar was used.

Comment: if you want this by using jquery refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/mu8esd41/1/. This will fulfill your expectation I think because if user reach the ends then only it will be begins the countdown.

Comment: @UdhayTitus This is what I want! Thanks. But there is one problem. I know the users and they dont scroll all the time till the end. Do you know what to change to start the countdown if the users scroll just a bit?

Comment: check the updated answer here https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/mu8esd41/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with `setTimeOut() function` and page idle

```js
  
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
       }, 5000);
   }
});

var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every second.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 10) { // 10 seconds
        idleTime = 0;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
    }
}
```

```css
#content {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Scroll &darr;</div>
```

Comment: can you delete to back to top button with style and js code for me? :) If I try to delet something, the code dont work anymore. Just need the function without the button :)

Comment: @wabizo check the updated answer. Now it is without scroll top button.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non jQuery version:

```js
var timeout;

function returnToTop() {
    if (!timeout) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("scrollable").scroll(0, 0);
            timeout = null;
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

```css
#scrollable {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#interior {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable" onscroll="returnToTop()">
  <div id="interior">
    scroll me!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! This is what I wanted!
Is it possible that the countdown will not begin until the user let go the scroll bar. Or is this too much? :)

Comment: This function will be called hundreds of times. If a user scroll then waits for a moment and scroll again, it will be moved by the first call to the top, if they scroll down then they will quickly be moved to the top again. That function should be debounced or throttle.

Comment: @Deykun Your right. If I scroll many time it just put me back after one second. What should be changed on this code to prevent it?

Comment: Added debounce.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the time in the setTimeout function.

```
var scrolltimer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(scrolltimer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    scrolltimer = setTimeout(function() {
          // do something
    }, 150);
}, false);
```